# What are the sufficient and necessary conditions for a unitary matrix to be written in a tensor product of 2x2 matrices?

Tags: tensor-products, unitary-matrices, tensor-decomposition

I understand an arbitrary unitary matrix cannot be always written in a tensor product of 2x2 matrices. But, if a unitary matrix meets some conditions, can it be done? If so, what are those conditions?

Answer (score 0):

The paper [Criterion of Local Unitary Equivalence for Multipartite States](https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.2042) answers your question.